# GET request works fine in Postman - 405 Not Allowed from Java code

Tags: api, http, postman, okhttp

I am trying to do a GET HTTP request to the following url: https://xml.betfred.com/horse-racing-us.xml

It gets blocked from my Java code using Apache or OKHTTP, but works every single time in Postman without any additional headers etc.

The response I get from my code is:

`Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=405, message=Not Allowed, url=https://xml.betfred.com/horse-racing-us.xml}`

Why is it working in Postman but nowhere else?

```java
    String URL = "https://xml.betfred.com/horse-racing-us.xml";

    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();

    headers.put("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    headers.put("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36");
    headers.put("Connection", "keep-alive");
    headers.put("accept", "application/json");

    JSONObject object = null;
    try {
        object = JSONHelper.readJsonFromUrl(URL, headers);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();


public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String urlString, HashMap<String, String> headers) throws IOException, JSONException {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    URL url = new URL(urlString);

    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    Iterator<Entry<String, String>> it = headers.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> pair = (Map.Entry<String, String>)it.next();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue());
    }

    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */ );
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */ );
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

    urlConnection.connect();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    br.close();

    String jsonString = sb.toString();

    urlConnection.disconnect();

    return new JSONObject(jsonString);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code to your question?

Comment: Code added. Thanks

Comment: I just tried with curl and also got a 405 but it works ok in the browser. They must be checking something to do with the user-agent

Comment: I don't think your `User-Agent` header is being applied correctly.

Comment: I did some testing and your code works fine for me. The only thing I can think of at this stage is that you have a typo in `User-Agent` in your actual code. FYI, you can shorten your header code to `headers.forEach(urlConnection::setRequestProperty)` if using any recent version of Java

Answer (score 0):

This message indicates, that the GET-Method for HTTP version 1.1 is not allowed.

It looks like a version mismatch. The website supports HTTP version 2, when you open it in the browser. You could try to replace Java's builtin `HttpUrlConnection` by OkHttp, because OkHttp supports HTTP version 2. You you must upgrade your JVM. In my JVM (build 1.8.0_241-b07), HTTP version 2 is choosen, when i run this code-snippet.